# Calculating mean of arrays from a txt file in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate mean of arrays in `Test.txt`. But I am getting an error. I present the contents of `Test.txt` as well as the expected output.

```
import ast
import numpy as np

file_path = "C:/Users/USER/OneDrive - Technion/Research_Technion/Python_PNM/Basics/Velocity_Average/Test.txt"
with open(file_path) as f:
    content = f.read()
    data = ast.literal_eval(content)

for arr in data:
    arr = np.array(arr)  # Convert the array to a NumPy array
    filtered_data = arr[arr > 1e-9]  # Filter elements greater than 1e-9
    mean = np.mean(filtered_data)
    print(mean)
```

The contents of `Test.txt` are

```
[array([[1.0],
       [2.0],
       [3.0],
       [4.0],
       [1e-12]])]
[array([[1.0],
       [2.0],
       [3.0],
       [4.0],
       [1e-12]])]
```

The error is

```
line 7
    [array([[1.0],
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The expected output is

```
[2.5,2.5]
```

Comment: the content of the file is illegal Python

Comment: the issue seems to be related to how the contents of `Test.txt` are formatted!

Comment: Yes that's the reason. How can I address this? The contents of the file are above.

Comment: Why would the answer be [2.5,2.5] when the means are actually [2.0000000000002,2.0000000000002] ?

Comment: After the operation `filtered_data = arr[arr > 1e-9]`, the means of `filtered_data` will be `[2.5, 2.5]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file you have string representations of Python lists between pairs of parentheses. The literal *array* is irrelevant.

You can isolate the lists using a regular expression.

```
from re import compile
from ast import literal_eval

FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.txt'
PATTERN = compile(r'(?<=\().+?(?=\))')

output = []

with open(FILENAME) as data:
    content = ''.join(map(str.rstrip, data))
    for m in PATTERN.findall(content):
        if (lst := literal_eval(m)):
            total = sum(e[0] for e in lst)
            mean = total / len(lst)
            output.append(mean)

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[2.0000000000002, 2.0000000000002]
```

**Note:**

This output differs from OP's requirements but does actually represent the correct mean values from the lists

Comment: This calculates the means of the lists themselves, but OP's code included a step `filtered_data = arr[arr > 1e-9]` and calculated the means of `filtered_data`.

Comment: @slothrop I had ignored the code and worked purely on the description which seems to have produced the correct result. I say that on the grounds that OP has accepted the answer. Of course, changing this code to ignore values less than or equal to 1e-9 is trivial and would produce an output of [2.0, 2.0]

Comment: Sure. I guess it at least sets to rest the question *"Why would the answer be [2.5,2.5] when the means are actually [2.0000000000002,2.0000000000002] ?"*

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
data = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in content.replace(
    '\n', '').replace('[array(', '').split(')]') if x]
[np.array(d)[np.array(d) > 1e-9].mean() for d in data]
```

Output:

```
[2.5, 2.5]
```